# ReactTestUtils is not defined. Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to simulate a click event in the Chrome extension.
I use ReactTestUtils to achieve this objective.
However, I get the following error when I trigger the event.

```
VM177635:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:386
    at <anonymous>:1:435
```

It looks like that I cannot load my dependencies properly to my google chrome extension.

Here is my simple code:

```js
import ReactTestUtils from "react-dom/test-utils";

const extension = () => {
  const element = getFocusedElement();
  ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(element as Element);
  console.log("I am loaded");
};
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting
    .executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tab.id ? tab.id : -1 },
      func: extension,
      args: [],
    })
    .then();
});
```

Here is the manifest file

```js
{
  "name": "prompt injector 004!",
  "description": "This extension is created to inject prompts to AI tools",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {},
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting", "windows"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
```

Here is the webpack

```js
const path = require("path");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: "./src/index.tsx",
  },
  mode: "production",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader",
            options: {
              compilerOptions: { noEmit: false },
            },
          },
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: "manifest.json", to: "../manifest.json" }],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist/js"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
};
```